# Setting Locale Not applying to custom dialogue

Tags: java, android

I have app in which I have below code in base activity.

```
String CurrentLang = sessionManager.getStringValue("UserLang");
Locale locale = new Locale(CurrentLang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(config);
        }
```

Its working fine in fragment and activity etc, However in custom dialogue, its showing default language. If user change language from setting menu, app restarting with base activity and its start showing custom language even in dialogue but when I remove application from recent app and start again, its showing again default language only for custom dialogue, other place its showing fine, Let me know if someone can help me for solve the puzzle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Resources resources=getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm=resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf=resources.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(new Locale(language/*e.g: en for english, ar for arabic ....etc*/));
    resources.updateConfiguration(conf,dm);
```

Then you have to restart your layout